# cannot send client side Image() object (created with canvas and jquery) to .net server

Tags: jquery, .net, html, canvas

As the title says, I'm trying to send an image that only exists client side back to the .net server. I am using a few very simple functions to accomplish this goal. I have no trouble creating and viewing the image, but I cannot find a solution that will allow me to post this image to the server. The functions I am using are included below. If additional code is needed, I will gladly provide it.

So, the first function creates the image following the example I found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas).

```
function createImage() {

var canvas = $('<canvas></canvas>')
        .attr("id", "image-canvas-for-upload-to-server");

var ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");

var data = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='"+ width + "' height='" + height + "'>" +
             "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" +
               "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>" +
                "<body>" +
                    $(".html-for-image").html() +
                "</body>" +
               "</div>" +
             "</foreignObject>" +
           "</svg>";

var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;

var svg = new Blob([data], { type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8" });

var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

var img = new Image();

img.src = url;

img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
};

return img;
```

This function works. The problem arises from the image only existing locally. If I "inspect element" and look at my resources, I can see the image there. I can also gain some information about the image.

```
    Dimensions: 42 × 42
    File size: x.xxKB
    MIME type: image/svg+xml
    URL: blob:http://localhost:port/5d9f0874-a2c6-4fa7-bdcb-6869c29b5077 (this guid-like path is always different)
```

The second function attempts to send the image to the server. But, I've been woefully unsuccessful at finding a solution. I'm running a .net mvc server.

```
    function sendEmail(text, image) {
    $.post("http://localhost:port/email/send",
    {
        fromEmailAddress: "sender@example.com", 
        toEmailAddress: "recipient@example.com",
        subject: "look at this image!",
        messageBody: text,
        image: image
    });
```

}

I've tried serializing the Image() object, .stringify(), sending the svg, sending the blob, calling canvas.toDataURL() [but it throws a security error], sending the raw html so that I could render the html inside of an email then the user could download it or screenshot it, and I've tried several other things too, but none of them have been successful.

If anyone could point me in the right direction for sending this image back to the server, that would be awesome.

Additionally, I have no idea how to convert this Image() object into a png, jpeg, base64, etc. on the client side.

Thank you for your time.